# Generating JSON from POJO for a specific scenario

Tags: java, json, api, pojo

I have used Jackson and JSONObject to generate a plain JSON - things are fine here. I have a specific case where my pojo looks like below and i need the JSON is the specified format.

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "login")
public class LoginApi implements IRestBean {

private String username;
private String password;
private String sfSessionId;
private String sfServerUrl;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getSfSessionId() {
    return sfSessionId;
}

public void setSfSessionId(String sfSessionId) {
    this.sfSessionId = sfSessionId;
}

public String getSfServerUrl() {
    return sfServerUrl;
}

public void setSfServerUrl(String sfServerUrl) {
    this.sfServerUrl = sfServerUrl;
}
}
```

The JSON that i am able to generate looks like this:

```
{
 "username" : null,
 "password" : null,
 "sfSessionId" : null,
 "sfServerUrl" : null
}
```

But this is not my requirement - i need the JSON in the below format so that my server accepts this as a valid JSON:

```
{
 "@type":"login",
 "username":"username@domain.com",
 "password":"password",
 "sfSessionId":null,
 "sfServerUrl":null
 }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show also your code for generating JSON from the class.

Comment: I am using the same ObjectMapper that you had mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `IRestBean` interface to include the [`@JsonTypeInfo`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@type")
public interface IRestBean {
    ...
}
```

Next, annotate the `LoginApi` class with [`@JsonTypeName`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeName.html):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "login")
@JsonTypeName("login")
public class LoginApi implements IRestBean {
    ...
}
```

These are both Jackson-specific annotations.

Comment: I am trying this, still things don't work as expected. Should i add anything to the mapper in my generation class?

Comment: This kind of solves my problem. Here is the change i did in the IRestBean interface: @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property="@type")

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation for "Vote Up" - sorry.. but Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @SharathShashidhar thanks for the additional details. If you don't mind, I'll edit the answer to include your comment, for any future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Add a private field to the POJO with the type.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "login")
public class LoginApi implements IRestBean {

    ...

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String getJsonType() {
        return "login";
    }

    ...
}
```

Note the use of `XmlAttribute` to automatically append an "@" to the name.